# Is it possible to put a DataTable on the parent of the page and in a Modal from page; each with their own initialization?

Tags: c#, datatables

I have a page with a DataTable on it. One of the columns has a collection of data represented by a name and a second column has a link which will pop-up a modal with a second DataTable on it. As the modal begins to display I receive the typical DataTable initialization error:

> "DataTables warning: table id=tablename - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3"

This may actually be 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to load 2 DataTables to a single page with 2
   completely different initialization settings?
2. Is it possible to load 2 DataTables to a single page with 1 of them being in a modal and both with 2 completely different initialization settings?

I've tried including `"Destroy: true"` to close out one initialization in order for the second to take over.

I've tried bringing in the CSS manipulations of the modal DataTable in to the page as opposed to importing them in from a site.css file (as the parent DataTable utilizes)

I've tried performing a `$("#modalTable").DataTable().ajax.reload()` after the modal displays.

```
columnDefs: [
                {
                    "targets": [1,2,3],
                    "className": "text-center"                            
                }
            ],
            pagingType: "simple_numbers",
            language: {
                search: '<div class="input-group">' +
                    '<span class="input-group-addon"style="background-color: white;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span> _INPUT_' +
                    '</div>',
                searchPlaceholder: 'Search for a Value...',
                lengthMenu: '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>' +
                    '<select class="form-control">' +
                    '<option value="15" selected> 15 </option>' +
                    '<option value="25"> 25 </option>' +
                    '<option value="50"> 50 </option>' +
                    '<option value="-1"> Everything </option>' +
                    '</select></div>',
                paginate: {
                    previous: '<span class="formats_previous">Previous</span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></span>',
                    next: '<span class="formats_next">Next</span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>'
                }                        
                }
```

The expectation is the DataTable on the parent page will display with the desired initialization manipulations in the `dom/pagination/language/etc` and when you click the link/button to the bring up the modal it loads with all of it's specific/separate initialization manipulations in the dom/pagination/language/etc.

Could you please advise me on the right solution for my case? Thanks.

Comment: The code snippet is the section of the initialization that will change. (Besides the actual API utilized)

Comment: yes to both questions ( multiple table example might help https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html ) - are you trying to re-use the same template though and getting the error because the JS is targeting the same id or something?

Comment: I concur with both yes responses. I threw together a rather sloppy jsfiddle the other day after posing this question and I was able to see that I could have 2 separate initializations. 

I believe in the code-base on the project I am working on there is a series of conflicts occurring which essentially is making the modal pop-up datatable initialization to not work properly or as anticipated.